# Is there any relationship between variability and independence?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

If the two variables have the same variability, does that mean they are independent?

Answer (score 6):

By "variability" do you mean "variance"? No, two variables can have the same variance and not be independent at all. For instance, take any random variable $X$ with defined variance, and take $Y=-X$. They have the same variance, and yet they are totally dependent.